# Navigation not returning to original position after class is removed

Tags: jquery, html, css

The code controls my navigation. Transitioning down on-screen when scrolled 300px. And transitions up off-screen when scrolled back up (scrolls with content <300px)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
      $('nav').addClass('stick');
      $('nav').css('top', '0');
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
      $('nav').removeClass('stick');
      $('nav').css('top', '100%'); // my suggestion but doesn't work
    }

  });

});
```

```css
header {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -ms-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -o-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  transition: top 0.75s ease;
}

nav.stick {
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100px;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav id="s-nav">
    ...
  </nav>
</header>
```

I need it to start off-screen and transition down ONLY when scrolled >300px (when .stick class is applied). The code works, but when I scroll back up (when .stick class is removed) the navigation is still up off-screen.

Comment: maybe because of `$('nav').css('top','100px');` ?

Comment: I tried with and without that. doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Seems to work as expected [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/3n4zqg70/). Can you explain what the issue is?

Comment: No exactly. In the fiddle when I scroll down it doesn't navigate down from off screen. And it doesn't return to it's original position

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want the element back in the original position it started in right? If so; try my adjusted below;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
      $('nav').addClass('stick');
      $('nav').css('top', '0');
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
      $('nav').removeClass('stick');
      $('nav').css('top', '0'); // try this.
    }

  });

});
```

```css
header {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -ms-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -o-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  transition: top 0.75s ease;
}

nav.stick {
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100px;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav id="s-nav">
    ...
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Problem is it just 'appears' at the top. I want it to animate down from the top when .stick class is applied. So it needs to start offscreen when it's applied